# nginx webdav upload file premissions

Tags: nginx, webdav

I am using nginx with http webdav module to upload files and delete files to server I am able to upload files successfully and delete but the issue I am facing is that files it uploads does not have execute permissions

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nginx nginx 1583670 Apr 19 17:20 startup.jpg
```

where as the folder it creates have all the permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 nginx nginx    4096 Apr 19 16:27 s
```

I tried adding rwx to the nginx config but I get error it works fine with rw but with x it gives error

```
Apr 19 17:23:20 CDNSTORE nginx[18386]: nginx: [emerg] invalid value "group:rwx" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/webdav.conf:11
```

Following is my nginx config

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root /home/webdav/files;
  client_body_temp_path   /home/webdav/tmp;

  location / {
    dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
   # dav_ext_methods  PROPFIND OPTIONS;
    create_full_put_path  on;
    dav_access  user:rw group:rwx all:rwx;
    autoindex  on;
    client_max_body_size  1G;   # File size limit for new files

    auth_basic  "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/webdav/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

I want the images files to be accessible from url for that need to set `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions  .
I dont want to use cron and shell to set permission because I need to create folders and subfolder on the fly and folder needs permission so webdav can delete so looking for a solution that nginx set permission when uploading the file

Comment: Same for me, I feel like execution permissions are not considered and triggers errors.
The http_dav_module code source : https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_dav_module.c
I dont know much about nginx code soruce but maybe there something there